# Split column into two new columns in a data.frame with unequal lengths

Tags: r

I've not been able to find a solution to a problem I'm dealing with in R. I have a data.frame with a column containing state and county separated by a space. The first two characters of every row in the column are the state. After the space, follows the county. I want to create two new columns with one being the state and the second being the county.

What I have:

```
VAR_A, VAR_B, ST_COUNTY
A, B, AZ MOVHAVE
A, B, NV ELKO
A, B, CA SAN BERNADINO
```

What I want:

```
VAR_A, VAR_B, ST,COUNTY
A, B, AZ, MOHAVE
A, B, NV, ELKO
A, B, CA, SAN BERNADINO
```

Let me know if anyone has some ideas on how to output a new data frame with the two new columns.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `substr` to get the first two characters and `substr` with `nchar` to get the remaining characters.

Comment: Can you supply some sample code so I can check it out?

Comment: Take a look at the help file for `?substr` to see what it does. As an example, try `substr(dat$ST_COUNTY, 1, 2)`.

Comment: @Jaap Not the best dupes, in my opinion, since `substr` would be more appropriate in this case. For example, consider "CA San Bernadino".

Comment: @lmo `df %>% separate(ST_COUNTY, c("ST","COUNTY"), sep = " ", extra = "merge")` works as expected (as is also explained in the 2nd link).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I always gloss over piped answers.

Comment: substr(dat$ST_COUNTY, 1, 2) works, thank you!